# Using epsilon-delta definition to solve problems.

Tags: limits, soft-question

One of my friends was struggling in understanding the definition of epsilon-delta definition of limits. Now he finally got the meaning of the definition. Now when we were using this definition as [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfLimit.aspx)(see example 2).
Here we first start from the right-hand side of the implication and then we simplify it and get something which looks like the left-hand side of implication and then we say that let $\delta=f(\epsilon)$ (some function of $\epsilon$). **And now finally we start from left side of implication and reach to the right-hand side of the implication.**

My friend is getting a problem in understanding that why we do the first process i.e. simplify the right side of the implication.

One day I was playing this [game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobirix.playmaze&hl=en) and then I thought that I can use it to clear my friends doubt but I don't know how.

Please help me in order to clear my friends doubt either by the help of the game above or by any other example.

Comment: You mentioned the Maze King game. Is this intentional? I do not see what this has got to limits

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Sir the situation is little bit same, so please think over and help me.